# Not enough power going through IRLZ44, activated by Arduino

Tags: arduino, mosfet, battery-operated, solenoid

I've a 9v battery and I'm trying to get 9v through my IRLZ44, to power an solenoid. It's a seperate system from my arduino who's sending a 5v signal to the  IRLZ44 in order to activate it.

For some reason i can not get more than 4.5v through my IRLZ44? What am I gonna doo???

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXqrjl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Tried drawing it as correctly as possible, but I'm super new to this. I'm sorry if i screwed up.

Comment: What is Vgs, Vgs and 9V reading? What Id do you expect?  Id=9V/DCR

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt I'm sorry, I don't know what VGS means, I'm trying to get atleast 9v through the IRLZ44N but i'm maximum getting out 4.5v off it.

Comment: Connect the 9V battery directly to the solenoid and measure the voltage across the solenoid. What do you get? ... Does the solenoid activate?... do not connect any other components.

Comment: @jsotola my batteries output 8,24v. When I connect the solenoid directly to the battery the multimeter says 7,48v.

Comment: Sorry. The solenoid reacts perfectly to the charge, it shoots out and then disconnected goes back to normal state.

Comment: Artonn I think you better start reading about FETs, Vgs and electronics in general. You have too much to learn. I can suggest google and expect that to take a few days to learn for you.

Comment: Was the problem solved ? Typically GND of both the power source must be connected to each other.
Also the solenoid power rating must be check before hand. Since you are using Mosfet IRLZ44N, which has a property to drop the voltage,
hence would suggest connect LED before connecting Solenoid, and check with Multimeter for voltage.

Comment: The problem has yet to be sovled. Thank you for your comment, I've updated the schematic to be correct with my setup. I've connected my multimeter directly to the Mosfet and it reads around 4.5V.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt Going to take some time, but I had hoped I would figure these things out as I worked with them. But you can also be fair to a newcommer. If you simply would had said voltage gate to source, our communication would have been a lot more productive, it's fine you don't feel like dealing with a newcommer, but no reason to make it more difficult. :) To answer your question, i'm sending 9v or 7.2v through the source and only around 4.5v comes out of the drain whenever i send a 5v signal to the gate.

Comment: I dont recommend you attempt to design anything until you understand the basics. So keep reading how they work and the jargon and most important how the specs differ and why they include these specs. Figure out how everything works by reading descrptions of designs. Then you can ask more intelligent questions.  Especially learn how to draw schematic layouts from the best.

Comment: I have a few solenoids with me ;share the specs of solenoid I will check and revert with code and schematics using 18650 batt

Comment: Hi Prashant. The solenoids spec is 6DC 300mA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "4.5v through my IRLZ44"? Do you mean "4.5V across the drain and source? When the mosfet is switched on, the drain to source voltage should be extremely low (millivolts). When off, the drain to source voltage should be 7.2V. If it is less than 7.2V when off, the mosfet may already be fried, and the drain to source may be partially shorted.

Check the gate voltage. It should be above 2V (peferably above 4V) for the mosfet to work properly. Also, there needs to be a high value resistor from gate to ground, for the mosfet gate capacitance to discharge when it is switched off (otherwise it will not switch off).

Decrease the value of the 1K resistor to the minimum required to not go over the arduino pin current limit. Operating the mosfet in the linear region with a lower gate voltage may shorten it's life.

Comment: Hi Indraneel. I have my two 18650 batteries ground connected to the source, while the drain is connected to the solenoid ground. The positive wire is connected directly to the battery. The Arduino nano sends a 5v signal to the gate, and the arduino nano ground is also connected to the ground of the battery. When measuring the voltage between the drain and the positive voltage of the battery, while activating my switch to send a 5v signal to the IRLZ44 gate it reads around 4.5v between the drain and my multimeter ground.

Comment: I'll check the voltage to the gate, to make sure it's 5v. It should be, but haven't actually checked it. I believe I might not be able to go lower than the 1k resistor, as far as I've been told. EDIT: BTW, When I deactivate the switch, the voltage reads 0.

Comment: Voltage is a potential difference between two points. Please specify both the points when you are measuring the voltage, otherwise it becomes difficult to understand what you are reporting.

Comment: Okay I think I might have found the problem, I took my multimeter and connected it to ground and to the digital pin 11. It says that there's being outputted 1.6V...